# Moving a preposition to after the object

Tags: словоупотребление, предлоги, стилистика

Curious as to what the Russians think about Japanese cars, I did some research and saw an [article](https://www.rbc.ru/society/26/12/2013/56bfbaa99a7947299f72d78f) with the following title:

> Не престижа ради, а токмо драйва для

I knew that **ради** is an exceptional preposition that can jump to after the object (e.g., "подайте Христа ради"), but was shocked to see **для** being used likewise. My world is shattered.

It turns out that Russians indeed used to talk like that, at least in the good old times of Peter the Great:

> **Того для** велите нынѣ вылить 300 пушек ... (from *Дѣяния Петра Великаго, Мудраго Преобразителя России*)
>
> Указ Синоду: «По делам следующимся в канцелярии Вышняго суда игумен Варлаам Овсянников и дьякон Чюркин явились в немалых преступлениях, по некоторым приличились они к розыску, **того для** велите с них священство и монашество снять» ([Source](https://spb.hse.ru/humart/history/peter/biochronic/248448010))
>
> А.Д.Меншикову письмо, пошедшему вперед: «Понеже здесь снег выпал немалой и не безопасно, чтоб не захватили морозы, **того для** велите примечать, ежели сверху по реке пойдет лед или сало, то с того ведомость пришли к нам на встречю немедленно» ([Source](https://spb.hse.ru/humart/history/peter/biochronic/228771804))
>
> **Того для** велите ему оную мызу отдать вмѣсто недоданнаго его жалованья до указу нашего безъ аренды. Екатерина. Изъ С.-Петербурга, въ 6 день марта 1726 года. ([Source](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F._%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC_4_(1883).djvu/203))

My question: How do people see moving prepositions like **для** to after the object in modern Russian? Is it considered grammatically wrong, just old-fashioned, or perfectly normal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, placing **для** after the noun does sound archaic.

> Не престижа ради, а токмо драйва для

The author of this piece obviously went for a comic effect by intertwining recent loanwords (престиж, драйв) with archaic vocabulary  (токмо, ... для).

This phrase seems to be modelled after a quote from Ilf & Petrov's *The Twelve Chairs* (1928):

> -- Не корысти ради, -- затянул отец Федор, поднявшись и отойдя на три шага от драцены. -- А токмо во исполнение воли больной жены.

There are other prepositions which can be used as postpositions without sounding archaic: час спустя, заре навстречу, etc. See the Wikipedia article [Послелог](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3).

Answer (score 8):

In modern Russian moving **для** to after the object is a sign of that speaking person wants to make her speech more archaic intentionally. It is not normal.

Comment: well, it's normal in that sense that it is intentionally used to sound archaic ;) welcome to the Russian SE !

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in other answers, using *для* after the subject makes the speaker sound archaic (intentionally or otherwise).  Yet it's worth noting that in your first example word *для* can be replace with *ради*, which you already accepts as being the exception (compare with *Не престижа ради, а токмо драйва ради*).

You wouldn't put *для* after the subject in a sentence like *мне это нужно для работы* (*мне это нужно работы для* is completely wrong).

So, from a grammatical point of view, you can place *для* after the subject in cases where *для* can be replaced with *ради* without changing the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

An addition to the previous answers.

The formula itself is originated from an ancient "meme" whose authorship is uncertain (but widely attributed to Peter the Great):

> Не пьянства окаянного ради, а токмо пользы для.

As far as I can remember, Peter's aphorisms gained specific popularity and became "memes" in the mid-1980s, giving birth to an extremely huge number of titles like the one you cite.